# angularJS watch for image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my app i have such view:

```
      <div class="r-container" image-crop>
        <img id="photo-cropper" src="">
      </div>
```

src for image is setting up in controller (after imageuploading to browser):

```
$scope.files = files;        
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  $('#photo-cropper').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

and then i have such directive (maybe there is a little bit jQuery style, but let's say it's ok):

```
.directive('imageCrop', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {  
        var $image, originalData;   

                angular.element("#image-crop-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
                    console.log('postLink');
                    $image = angular.element(".r-container > img");
                  originalData = {};
                  $image.cropper({
                    multiple: true,
                    aspectRatio: 1.5,
                    data: originalData,
                    done: function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                    }
                  });
                });
                angular.element("#save-cropper").click(function() {
                  originalData = $image.cropper("getDataURL");
                  console.log(originalData);
                  angular.element('#image-crop-modal').modal('hide');
                  scope.setCroppedData(originalData);
                  $image.cropper("destroy");
                });

      }
    };
  });
```

and so this imageCropper is applyed only, if in view code i define src by default, when i change it in controller: nothing happens - cropper didn't work: but why? How to set it on new image src?

Comment: can you show this function please? scope.setCroppedData(originalData);

Comment: Put directive on the image  and should be using scope for the image `ng-src`. Use `$apply` whenever you change scope with third party code so angular knows to run a digest

Comment: @micha http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/ events from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular's controller, changing the DOM manually is not suggested. You'd better use directive to handle content change as Angular will trigger the so called `digest loop` to check whether content binded to DOM element has been modified and update the DOM accordingly.

In you view, use ng-src instead of src and move the directive on element `<img>`:

```
<div class="r-container">
  <img id="photo-cropper" ng-src="imagecontent" image-crop>
</div>
```

Then in your directive, you can read the content from `$scope.imagecontent`. In the same way, when you want to update the content, you need to execute following code:

```
$scope.evalAsync(function() {
  $scope.imagecontent = newContent;  
});
```

Once `$scope.imagecontent` is updated, the DOM would be refreshed by Angular automatically. So I suppose, the crop method in your directly may be like this:

```
$image.cropper({
   multiple: true,
   aspectRatio: 1.5,
   data: $scope.imagecontent,
   done: function(data) {
     $scope.evalAsync(function() {
       $scope.imagecontent = data;  
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: hm, seems that still only image without plugin executed

Comment: It would be better you can share the code with us for debugging

Comment: code sharing - unreal) to many code here)   also ... when i add link, and set not `angular.element("#image-crop-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {` but on click of this link - it's executed